# How to get attribute codes of super product attributes of a configurable product

Tags: magento

For example, a configurable product with attributes Size and Color, I need to get the attribute codes of the above attributes.

or to be more specific, I need to know whether an attribute is used to configure a configurable product. I need this to check at product list page

Answer (score 4):

try using this code

```
$config_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($config_product_id);
$productAttributeOptions = $config_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($config_product);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I used the following code to get the results
$_attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductAttributeIds($_product);

Answer (score 0):

Create an array as shown below:

```
$attributeValues['additional_options'][$count]['label'] = $aAttr['name'];
$attributeValues['additional_options'][$count]['value'] = $aAttr['value'];
```

Then pass the array while adding items to the order:

```
if (!empty($product['product_options'])) {
    $orderItem->setProductOptions($product['product_options']);
}
```

Here `$product['product_options']` is the array that we have created in the first step.